# Proof Explanation for Showing Equivalent Definition of Independent Events

Tags: probability, solution-verification, proof-explanation, independence

Given events $\{ A_i \}_{i = 1} ^k$. They are mutually independent or $k$-wise independent if $\forall I \subseteq \{ 1, \cdots, k \}$
$$
\mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i \cap \bigcap_{i \in I^c} A_i^c) = \prod_{i \in I} \mathbb{P}(A_i) \prod_{i \in I^c} \mathbb{P}(A_i^c).
$$

It is claimed equivalently,$A_1, \cdots, A_k$ are mutually independent or $k$-wise independent if $\forall I \subseteq \{ 1, \cdots, k \}$
$$
\mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i) = \prod_{i \in I}\mathbb{P}(A_i)
$$
Proof is given in the lecture note and I will present only the piece that I do not understand:

> Fix any non-empty $I \subseteq \{ 1, \cdots, k \}$. Let $\mathcal{L}$ be the set of all subsets of indices $J$ s.t. $I \subseteq J \subseteq \{ 1, \cdots, k \}$:
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{J \in \mathcal{L}} \mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i \cap \bigcap_{i \in J \setminus I} A_i \cap \bigcap_{i \in J^c} A_i^c) &= \sum_{J \in \mathcal{L}} \prod_{i \in I} \mathbb{P}(A_i) \prod_{i \in J \setminus I} \mathbb{P}(A_i) \prod_{i \in J^c} \mathbb{P}(A_i^c) \\
> &= \prod_{i \in I} \mathbb{P}(A_i) \sum_{J \in \mathcal{L}} \prod_{i \in J \setminus I} \mathbb{P}(A_i) \prod_{i \in J^c} \mathbb{P}(A_i^c) \\
> &= \prod_{i \in I} \mathbb{P}(A_i) \prod_{i \in I^c}(\mathbb{P}(A_i) + \mathbb{P}(A_i^c)) \\
> &= \prod_{i \in I} \mathbb{P}(A_i) \cdot 1 \\
> &= \prod_{i \in I} \mathbb{P}(A_i).
> \end{align*}

I do not understand
$$
\sum_{J \in \mathcal{L}} \prod_{i \in J \setminus I} \mathbb{P}(A_i) \prod_{i \in J^c} \mathbb{P}(A_i^c) = \prod_{i \in I^c}(\mathbb{P}(A_i) + \mathbb{P}(A_i^c))
$$
appearing in the third equation above. Why is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}}$Expand: $$\prod_{i\in I^c}(\P(A_i)+\P(A_i^c))$$You will get a sum of products of form $\P(A_{k_1})\P(A_{k_2})\cdots\P(A_{k_a})\P(A_{m_1}^c)\P(A_{m_2}^c)\cdots\P(A^c_{m_b})$ where the indices $k_\bullet,m_\bullet$ may be any indices not in $I$, with the only restrictions being that $k_x$ is distinct from every $m_y$ and that the $\{k_1,\cdots,k_a,m_1,\cdots,m_b\}$ enumerate $I^c$.

*There are no repeats*: each summand has a unique associated set of $k_\bullet,m_\bullet$.

To each summand we can associate the index set $J=I\sqcup\{k_1,\cdots,k_a\}$. Then necessarily we have $\{m_1,\cdots,m_b\}=J^c$. $J\in\mathcal{L}$ of course, and we find each sumamnd equal to $\prod_{i\in J\setminus I}\P(A_i)\prod_{i\in J^c}\P(A_i^c)$ for a unique such $J$. Conversely, for every possible $J\in\mathcal{L}$, there is such a summand. This gives the desired equality.